# Setting a REG-BINARY value for a key in the Registry. - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, registry

I am creating a tool to change a key in the Registry. The RegistryKey I want to set is a REG_BINARY and what I want it to change to is a textbox-entry.

So in this case, the formatting of the key i want to set it to, is sort of like this:

```
C9-0E-E8-04-4E-T6-E8-30-69-1B-E4-B7-63-5C-B2
```

I've tried doing this and also set i up like a `New Byte() {}` value. Also, I corrected the formatting, replaced the "-" with ", &H".
Which basically makes it:

```
"&H06, &H0E, &HE8, &H04, &H4E, &H62, &HE8, &H30, &H69, &H1B, &H58, &HB7, &H63, &H5C, &H7F"
```

I figured this was the only way to get the information the program needs to automatically work with the `New Byte() {}`-method I am using below (A better way of doing this is part of my question).

This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim Test As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim Test2 As String = Test.Replace("-", ", &H")
Dim Test3 = "&H" + Test2
Dim keys As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\etc\etc", True)
keys.SetValue("Key", New Byte() {Test3})
```

Here, the problem lies in (I believe):

```
keys.SetValue("Key", New Byte() {Test3})
```

And I get a `Conversion from string "Test3-string" to 'Byte' is not valid.` error, because I simply can't convert it like that.

How do I get the program to automatically convert the `TextBox1` entry to a compatible REG-BINARY key and successfully set it to the Registry? Eventually using a more efficient way than the one above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings just can’t be turned into arrays like that. What you can do, however, is split on `-` and convert each part to a `Byte`.

```
Dim bytes() As Byte = Array.ConvertAll(
                          TextBox1.Text.Split("-"c),
                          Function(b) Convert.ToByte(b, 16)
                      )
keys.SetValue("Key", bytes)
```

Comment: Hmm, this just gives me a "Argument not specified for parameter 'converter' pf 'Public Shared Function [...]"-error. 

I am probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @user2489613: Sorry, I got the argument and `Array` mixed up! (`ConvertAll` isn’t quite the same as `Select`). Try again.